# Node Update - Overlay

Tags: nodes, modal-dialogs

I have a problem on saving a specific node. When I try to save it the overlay doesn't disappear, but the node is correctly saved and updated.
If I change node title everything works good.

I attach an image below:

[image]

Comment: I see that the problem happens everytime I use the word "Advertising" at the beginning of a title. I've also tried to delete the node manually from the DB but the problem still remain.

Comment: Try disabling jquery update module and may be disabling your ad block adding too.

Comment: It was just add block, thank you. Is there any ways to solve this problem with ad block?